# Angular 2 RC 5 Injector undefined

Tags: angular, rootscope

I have a Injector Procedure. The Injector give me a unique instance from a service and then I can use the Service like a static class in c# or the rootScope. In RC5 the Injector is always undefined. What alternatives do I have?

```js
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

let appInjectorRef: Injector;

export const appInjector = (injector?: Injector): Injector => {
    if (injector) {
        appInjectorRef = injector;
    }

    return appInjectorRef;
};
```

GlobalService:

```js
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class GlobalService {

    @Output()
    UsernameChanged = new EventEmitter<String>();
    LoggedInChanged = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();
    WaitGifChanged = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();

    private loggedIn: boolean;
    private username: string = "Username";
    private waitGif: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        this.loggedIn = false;
    }

    public showWaitGif() {
        this.waitGif = true;
        this.WaitGifChanged.emit(true);
    }

    public hideWaitGif() {
        this.waitGif = false;
        this.WaitGifChanged.emit(false);
    }

    public Login(): void {
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this.LoggedInChanged.emit(true);
    }

    public Logout(): void {
        this.loggedIn = false;
        this.LoggedInChanged.emit(false);
    }

    public GetUsername(): string {
        return this.username;
    }

    public SetUsername(username: string): void {
        this.username = username;
        this.UsernameChanged.emit(this.username);
    }



    public GetLoggedInStatus(): boolean {
        return this.loggedIn;
    }

    public LoginCheck(): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.create((observer => {
            return (this.loggedIn);
        }));// (this.loggedIn);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```js
private LoginUser(username: string, password: string): void {
        let injector: Injector = appInjector();
        var globalService: GlobalService = injector.get(this.globalservice);
        this.globalservice.Login();
        this.globalservice.SetUsername("Test 1");
    }
```

Bootstrap:

```js
import {Globalservice} from './Service/Globalservice';
import {Component, provide, Injector, ComponentRef/*, ViewResolver*/} from '@angular/core/index.d';
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.d';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {appInjector} from './app.injector';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import {provideRouter, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterConfig, provideRoutes } from '@angular/router';
import {AppResolver}     from './app.resolver';
import {AppComponent}     from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
        provideRoutes,
        provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
        provide(Window, { useValue: window }),
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        Globalservice,
        provide(ViewResolver, { useClass: AppResolver })
        ]).then((appRef: ComponentRef) => {
            appInjector(appRef.injector);
        });

]);
```

AppModule

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {AppsAdminComponent} from './AppsAdmin/AppsAdmin.component';
import {AppsManagerComponent} from './AppsManager/AppsManager.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './Login/login.component';
import {LogoutComponent} from './Logout/logout.component';
import { Routing }  from './App.routing';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {AppsManagerService} from './Service/AppsManager.service';
import {GlobalService} from './Service/GlobalService';
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {SharedModule} from './Shared/Shared.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        LogoutComponent,
        AppsAdminComponent,
        AppsManagerComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        Routing
    ],
    providers: [
        GlobalService
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to be defined? What service?

Comment: i want to get a unique class (service is maby not the right name)  for store variables like 'Is User loggedin' and so on. One Class that have in all components the same information

Comment: At first, this doesn't sound like a great idea. It seems you're trying to work entirely against Angular. 2nd you mention a service but don't show the code. From above code I wouldn't expect any behavior, therefore I'm asking why do you expect one.

Comment: i add the service and the usage

Comment: i added the bootstrap and AppModule. I forgot it sry. This worked before i update to RC 5. In RC 5 the ViewResolver was removed so I can't use this solution no longer. What can i do now

Comment: What do you get from a `console.log(appRef.injector)` in the `bootstrap(...).then(...)` callback? I still don't understand why you think you need this. This was a hack for `@CanActivate()` for the old router but shouldn't be necessary anymore.

Comment: I have updated to RC 5. This bootstrap that i posted does no longer exsists. The new Bootstrap for RC 5 is 'platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);' and there i cant do '.then'. Also ViewResolver was removed. What other Solution do i have to get a static Class in Angular 2

Comment: Why do you need a static class? You can also inject the injector in a normal service and then call `appInjector(injector)` from there.

Comment: i need a static class where i can define variables like 'is user loggedIn' or show and hide a wait.gif and so on. 

When i execute the method LoginUser then will i get a undefined injector

Comment: I scatched it http://i.epvpimg.com/Qf6kh.png All Components get and modify Globalservice variables. Globalservice is a service where the information in all components the same. When i modify .gif to show in AppMangerComponent this will be change in all other components

Comment: For this you don't need anything special, just provide the `GlobalService` in the root `NgModule` and inject it where you need it.

Comment: i just tested it. When I execute LoginUser that modify 2variables. After that I inject Globalservice in my Component and there are these variables at default value

Comment: I don't know without seeing what you tried. If you make a call to a server, the response to this request might not have arrived. You'd need observables to notify about the response from the server. Your static injector wouldn't help you with this problem at all.

Comment: I set with the method LoginUser the Username "Test 1" in LoginComponent. In an other Component like AppManagerComponent I read this variable and the value is "Username". I import GlobalService in both Component and declare it in the constructor and I provide it in the NgModule.

Comment: But I don't see **how** you do it. If you do a server call there, the response is not available immediately after you send the call, but only when the callback passed to `.subscribe(...)` is executed which is usually a **very long time** after you sent the `this.http.get()` (relative to the amount of work the browser does in the same time internally). Your components are constructed and they check the value in `LoginComponent`, then the browser is idling for a **very long time**, tthen the response arrives and sets the login state.

Comment: I don't use http because i only want to test globalservice. I execute LoginUser with
                this.globalservice.Login();
  this.globalservice.SetUsername("PETER HANNES");
  this.nagivagteToHome();

and then i read in AppManagerComponent globalservice.GetUserName(). Can you give me a simple example with 2 componets and one module. One Component save into a service and the second read the setted value out?

Comment: Actually I still don't understand what you try to accomplish. I think at first you should get rid of any mention of `injector` in your code and just let Angular do the work. Define the dependency as required and if something doesn't work, then post a question that shows what you tried and what doesn't work as expected.

Comment: i have removed all with injector. I don't unterstand what is wrong. Can you give me a simple example with 2 componets and one module. One Component save into a service and the second read the setted value out?

Comment: I saw you have `@Output()` in `GlobalService`. `@Output()` in a service isn't doing anything. It is only for components and directives. You can check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service. There is not much difference in communicating between components and services. Also when you don't use `http.get()` if one service is constructed before the other and one checks the value and then the other sets it you have the same problem as explained with `http.get()`.

Comment: If you use `BehaviorSubject` and subscribe to it then you get either the value emitted previously or get notified immediately when a value was emitted.

Comment: I tried to change it but now i get the error: "No provider for GlobalService!" in LoginComponent. Here is my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/8lRvnLCSSgcx8c7sLwiM What is wrong. I provide it in the NgModule

Comment: The "live example" link provides a ready-to-use Plunker template https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html Also the "new" button in Plunker has an option for Angular2 (TS).

Comment: i put my code there because in the answer function i cant do some wordwraps. Only for show my code not for "live example"

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/z0EQmP2yISTb8HXMi1gk?p=preview

Comment: thanks thanks thanks a lot. i have one question. When i provide a service in ngModule and use this service in an other service and call this "other service" in an component then i get the error that the first service is not provide. Can i do that service from service with providing the first service in ngModule?

Comment: Would you mind forking and updating my Plunker to reproduce the problem. I don't see a way to diagnose the problem with this info.